# Custom User role not working with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, users, user-roles

I am currently working on making a custom user role "adoption_agency". Along with this custom role, i have created a custom post type called "adoptions". I have given "administrators" and "shop_manager" full access to this post type, which should allow them to delete, update or edit the post. When I login as an "adoption_agency" , "shop_manager" or "administrator" user I am able to view the custom post type on my dashbaord and i am able to access it. The issue i am having is that when I go to add new adoption and publish it, it says "You are not allowed to edit this post." I would like for the "adoption_agency" users to only have the "adoptions" post type available on their dashboards.  I have added my code below, I have been trying for a few days now and i cant seem to get it working. I would really appreciate the help.

Here is the my custom post type code:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type_adoption() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'adoptions', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'adoption', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Adoptions', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Adoptions', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Adoption Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Adoptions', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Adoption Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Adoption Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Adoption list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'adoption', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post type for Adoptions', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-smiley',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type' => array("adoption", "adoptions"),
    );
    register_post_type( 'adoptions', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_adoption', 0 );
```

Here is my custom user role code:

```
function add_adoption_caps_to_admin() {
  $caps = array(
    'read',
    'read_adoptions',
    'read_private_adoptions',
    'edit_adoptions',
    'edit_private_adoptions',
    'edit_published_adoptions',
    'edit_others_adoptions',
    'publish_adoptions',
    'delete_adoptions',
    'delete_private_adoptions',
    'delete_published_adoptions',
    'delete_others_adoptions',
    'upload_files',
    'edit_files',

  );
  $roles = array(
    get_role( 'administrator' ),
    get_role( 'editor' ),
    get_role( 'shop_manager' ),
  );
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    foreach ($caps as $cap) {
      $role->add_cap( $cap );
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_adoption_caps_to_admin' );


function adoption_agency_setup() {
  add_role( 'adoption_agency', 'Adoption Agency');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'adoption_agency_setup' );




function add_adoption_caps_to_non_admin_roles() {
  # Everyone gets these capabilities:
  $caps = array(
    'read',
    'read_adoptions',
    'read_private_adoptions',
    'edit_adoptions',
    'edit_published_adoptions',
    'publish_adoptions',
    'delete_adoptions',
    'delete_published_adoptions',
    'upload_files',
    'edit_files',
  );
  $roles = array(

    get_role( 'adoption_agency' ),

  );
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    foreach ($caps as $cap) {
      $role->add_cap( $cap );
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_adoption_caps_to_non_admin_roles' );




function custom_remove_menus(){

    // Get current user's data
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    // Check user's roles
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if( in_array( 'adoption_agency', $user->roles ) ) {
            // Remove menu items
            remove_menu_page( 'upload.php');
            remove_menu_page( 'index.php');

        }
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_remove_menus' );
```

Comment: You need to map the custom post type's `capability_type`. Check that argument on this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

Comment: What do you see when you look at `$GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['adoptions']`?

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would try to clarify my comments:

You only get a few things out of setting your `capability_types` the way you have above, which it is explained in [Note 2](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) of **capabilities**.

Here is what I see looking at `$GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['adoptions']->cap`:

```
stdClass Object(
    [edit_post] => edit_adoption
    [read_post] => read_adoption
    [delete_post] => delete_adoption
    [edit_posts] => edit_adoptions
    [edit_others_posts] => edit_others_adoptions
    [publish_posts] => publish_adoptions
    [read_private_posts] => read_private_adoptions
    [create_posts] => edit_adoptions
)
```

Once I add `'map_meta_cap'  => true,` to your post type `$args` I get a much more complete object:

```
stdClass Object(
    [edit_post] => edit_adoption
    [read_post] => read_adoption
    [delete_post] => delete_adoption
    [edit_posts] => edit_adoptions
    [edit_others_posts] => edit_others_adoptions
    [publish_posts] => publish_adoptions
    [read_private_posts] => read_private_adoptions
    [read] => read
    [delete_posts] => delete_adoptions
    [delete_private_posts] => delete_private_adoptions
    [delete_published_posts] => delete_published_adoptions
    [delete_others_posts] => delete_others_adoptions
    [edit_private_posts] => edit_private_adoptions
    [edit_published_posts] => edit_published_adoptions
    [create_posts] => edit_adoptions
)
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, forgot to add the  'capability_type' => array('adoption', 'adoptions'), 'map_meta_cap'    => true, however i am still having an issue. the "adoption_agency" user is able to edit admin and shop_manager posts. do you have an idea why?

Comment: Ok, yes. You will want to then REMOVE the `map_meta_cap` line, and custom map like explained here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types

Comment: Basically, this allows the capability only when the specific post type is being manipulated. Hope that makes sense, and you get to your goal.

Comment: so basically i would have to do my own mapping. I have removed the line  'map_meta_cap'    => true, and added the add_filter( 'map_meta_cap... but it is still not working. It is still allowing the adoption_agency user to have full control.

Comment: You will want to be sure to edit the `adoption_agency` role capabilities appropriately.

Comment: I have removed any cap that has the words other in it, so that the adoption_agency does not have any control of others adoptions. admins have the cap edit_others_adoptions while the adoption_agency does not. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37340/discussion-between-nathan-powell-and-steamfunk).